# Regex that doesnt match 0 at the beginning for every group

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

1. 01 Ded.PASIVIC 05-01-2016.xlsx
2. 01 Ded.PASIVIC 15-01-2016.xlsx
3. 01 Ded.PASIVIC 10-01-2016.xlsx
4. 06 DED. PASIVIC 30-03-2016 (1).xlsx
5. 19 DEDUCCION PASIVIC DEL 15-10-2016.xlsx (2)
6. 23 DEDUCCION PASIVIC DEL 15-12-2016.xlsx (1)
7. 18 APORTE PASIVIC DEL 30-09-2016.xlsx

I would like to  get the date that is printed on the name of the files **above**
but without leading zeros. 
[image]

Instead of getting the whole date as I'm doing above, I want to get for the first file **5-1-2016**, for the second file I want **15-1-2016**, for the third **10-1-2016** and so on (**NO LEADING ZEROS**).

The expected output should be like this:

1. 5-1-2016
2. 15-1-2016
3. 10-1-2016
4. 30-3-2016
5. 15-10-2016
6. 15-12-2016
7. 30-9-2016

I'm doing this on **python**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match 3 groups and for the first 2 groups match an optional zero followed by capturing 1 or 2 times a digit `0?([0-9]{1,2}-)` followed by a dash.

You might add a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b` at the start and at the end.

[`^.*?\b0?([0-9]{1,2}-)0?([0-9]{1,2}-)([0-9]{4})\b.*$`](https://regex101.com/r/6O0v52/1)

Then you could use [sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) and in the replacement use the capturing groups:

`\1\2\3`

```
import re
regex = r"^.*?\b0?([0-9]{1,2}-)0?([0-9]{1,2}-)([0-9]{4})\b.*$"
test_str = "01 Ded.PASIVIC 05-01-2016.xlsx"
subst = r"\1\2\3"
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 1)

if result:
    print (result) # 5-1-2016
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/LGX66133)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in two steps with `re.findall` and `re.sub`:

```
import re

data = """
01 Ded.PASIVIC 05-01-2016.xlsx 
01 Ded.PASIVIC 15-01-2016.xlsx 
01 Ded.PASIVIC 10-01-2016.xlsx 
06 DED. PASIVIC 30-03-2016 (1).xlsx 
19 DEDUCCION PASIVIC DEL 15-10-2016.xlsx (2) 
23 DEDUCCION PASIVIC DEL 15-12-2016.xlsx (1) 
18 APORTE PASIVIC DEL 30-09-2016.xlsx
"""

matches = re.findall('(?:[0-9]{2}-){2}[0-9]{4}',data)
print(re.sub('0(?=[0-9]-)','',str(matches)))
```

Prints:

```
['5-1-2016', '15-1-2016', '10-1-2016', '30-3-2016', '15-10-2016', '15-12-2016', '30-9-2016']
```

Answer (score 1):

In the most primitive way I would go with this solution:

([1-9])([0-9])-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)|([0-9])-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)